# How Send Cookie and Payload to Broker?

Tags: python, c#, cookies, httpwebrequest, payload

I need to send a buy request to my broker from c#.
when i send this request from google chrome, right click > inspect > network > Postdata give me this informations:

---

**General**

```
> Request URL: https://api2.mofidonline.com/Web/V1/Order/Post Request
> Method: POST Status Code: 200  Remote Address: 109.94.166.83:443
> Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

**Response Headers**

```
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-origin: https://www.mofidonline.com
api-supported-versions: 1.0
content-encoding: gzip
content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8
date: Sat, 25 Sep 2021 20:46:10 GMT
set-cookie: TS0182ab0d=0180bb6f2279578c94b3b606e45b8e8836f5652f16390e58a9d78a748f534b2a9f44b16e8f6f38db6302791734e4522bb1cd199d2a; Path=/; Domain=.api2.mofidonline.com
vary: Accept-Encoding
vary: Origin
```

**Request Headers**

```
:authority: api2.mofidonline.com
:method: POST
:path: /Web/V1/Order/Post
:scheme: https
accept: */*
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9,fa;q=0.8
authorization: BasicAuthentication ca4f8b23-2921-4f51-ab7c-ed9fcb04bb4d
content-length: 372
content-type: application/json
origin: https://www.mofidonline.com
referer: https://www.mofidonline.com/
sec-ch-ua: "Google Chrome";v="93", " Not;A Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="93"
sec-ch-ua-mobile: ?0
sec-ch-ua-platform: "Windows"
sec-fetch-dest: empty
sec-fetch-mode: cors
sec-fetch-site: same-site
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/93.0.4577.82 Safari/537.36
```

**Request Payload**

```
{IsSymbolCautionAgreement: false, CautionAgreementSelected: false, IsSymbolSepahAgreement: false,…}
CautionAgreementSelected: false
FinancialProviderId: 1
IsSymbolCautionAgreement: false
IsSymbolSepahAgreement: false
SepahAgreementSelected: false
isin: "IRT1PLSH0001"
maxShow: 0
minimumQuantity: 0
orderCount: 1000
orderId: 0
orderPrice: 82870
orderSide: 65
orderValidity: 74
orderValiditydate: null
shortSellIncentivePercent: 0
shortSellIsEnabled: false
```

---

how can i send this information manual with httpwebrequest ( or any way other)? Please help me...

Comment: no one can help me?

Comment: problem solved easy with Postman program